# PyQGIS composer add picture by layer path field

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer, atlas

I want to create an atlas composer map using PyQGIS 3.

How can I take dynamic path by field from atlas layer?

[image]
[image]

In PyQGIS 3 I need some like this :

```
pict = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
pict.setPicturePath(myAtlas['pict'])
pict.setFrameEnabled(True)
```

where `myAtlas` is my `layer` and `pict` is my field with paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the expression, you should use the following

```
if(
  file_exists(attribute(@atlas_feature, 'pict')),
  attribute(@atlas_feature, 'pict'),
  '/tmp/fallback.png'
)
```

For manipulating expressions, you should use

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayoutItemPicture

project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('atlas')

# By default, when you create any component in the layout component, no Item ID, so set it before
item = layout.itemById('theidoftheQgsLayoutItemPicture')
your_atlas_field = 'pict'
expression = "if(\n  file_exists(attribute(@atlas_feature, '{field}')),\n  attribute(@atlas_feature, '{field}'),\n  '/tmp/fallback.png'\n)".format(field=your_atlas_field)
item.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.PictureSource).setExpressionString(expression)
item.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.PictureSource).setActive(True)
```