# Remove QgsLayoutItemPicture based on atlas if the path does not exist with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, atlas

Based on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362711/pyqgis-composer-add-picture-by-layer-path-field/362712#362712) and answer (that works perfectly) I was wondering if I can **remove** the `QgsLayoutItemPicture` from the atlas pages where the picture path does not exist using PyQGIS.

One workaround I found is to set the expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN file_exists("My_Path" ) THEN 0
ELSE 1
END
```

in the `Rendering` option of the `QgsLayoutItemPicture` but I'm looking for a more *solid* solution:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayoutItemPicture

project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('atlas')

# the following code should be activated only if the `My_Path` file exists for the exported atlas feature:

my_atlas_picture = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
my_atlas_picture.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(267.207, 114.403, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters)) # whatever measures and 

my_atlas_picture.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.PictureSource).setExpressionString("My_Path")
my_atlas_picture.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.PictureSource).setActive(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert 'My_Path' validation before using the 'os' library, like this:

```
import os
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayoutItemPicture

project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('atlas')
My_Path = "" # Define here your path or use your variable


# the following code should be activated only if the `My_Path` file exists for the exported atlas feature:
if os.path.exists(My_Path):
    my_atlas_picture = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
    my_atlas_picture.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(267.207, 114.403, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters)) # whatever measures and 

    my_atlas_picture.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.PictureSource).setExpressionString(My_Path)
    my_atlas_picture.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.PictureSource).setActive(True)
```

Comment: I'm not convinced. `My_Path` is the name of a field of the atlas coverage layer. Therefore I can check if it exists **only** when the atlas is activated and the expression is interpreting the `My_Path` as the full path of the picture

Comment: Just add the check variation after the atlas selection solution, just where the variable will be declared. In your request it is not clear what you want only after this moment.
In short, you can build the path you want and test the existence of the path

Comment: Correct, I summarized a question that in my case is more complicated. The code I pasted is part of a plugin. So I have some layout (as `qpt`) that the user can choose to open. Some of this layouts are atlas based and the `My_Path` variable is the name of a filed of the coverage layer. The user is then exporting the layout with the standard QGIS button.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. Not straightforward, but it seems working.

A custom slot can be created that is called whenever the signal [featureChanged](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsLayoutAtlas.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutAtlas.featureChanged) of the `QgsLayoutAtlas` object is fired.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayoutItemPicture

project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('atlas')

# in this example a coverage layer is already set up in the layout
atlas = layout.atlas()

# custom function that will be called when the signal is fired
def update_feature_atlas(feature):
    picture = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
    picture.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(267.207, 114.403, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    
    # checking for each feature if the My_Path in not NULL
    if feature["My_Path"]:
        picture.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.PictureSource).setExpressionString("My_Path")
        picture.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.PictureSource).setActive(True)

    else:
        picture.setPicturePath("_my_other_path")


atlas.featureChanged.connect(update_feature_atlas)
```

Hoping this is also helping someone else, and of course I'm more than open to other solutions!